# Blender 3.0 Cycles Render Devices Missing - Mac Pro Monterey

Tags: osx

I've been trying to read all the information I can on the new Cycles X AMD GPU support and thought Blender 3.0 would have the HIP option for AMD GPUs but the option is not populating in the Preferences > System window.

Mac Pro 2019
3.3GHz 12‑core Intel Xeon W processor
Radeon Pro W6800X, 32GB

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that version 3.0.0 only supports Rdna cards (like 6000 series)and Radeon Pro 21.Q4 driver+ if I read the information correctly, 3.1.0 should add more support but this is completely on AMD side being slow, not the Blender... It works on my workstation with 6700XT but doesn't work on my personal RX 580

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You can't (right now). In March, it will be ready. Long Answer: If you really want to do it and you have no patience, here are the steps.

Step 1: Go to https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram and create an Apple Beta account. Download the latest beta of macOS Monterey 12.3 Beta 3. After the update is complete, proceed to step 2.

Step 2: Go to https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/ and download any version of EITHER Blender 3.2 Alpha or 3.1 Beta, as long as it is February 16th or newer. (I recommend just downloading the newest). After doing this. Open up Blender and in the preferences, it should show your GPU. I've the same model and it is working for me. After selecting the GPU, go into rendered view in Cycles with GPU compute selected. It will say it is loading render kernels, and that is okay. Depending on the hardware of your computer, wait 1-5 minutes and after the kernels load, it should be good.

Note: Kernels will have to load every time you download a new version of Blender and/or update your Mac. However, the kernels will not have to reload every time you go into rendered view, only if you update.

Hope this helps.